# How to set application_Version of trace in Python using azure.monitor.opentelemetry

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-application-insights, open-telemetry

In my traces I want to record the version of my application so that I can filter per build. The Traces table of ApplicationInsights has a column application_Version and I assume that's the one to use.

I can't find how to do it from Python but according to this article it seems possible:
[How can I set the Application Version number in Azure Application Insights for User and Exception data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942958/how-can-i-set-the-application-version-number-in-azure-application-insights-for-u#45949750)

Looks like I should use the SERVICE_VERSION attribute:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-python/blob/41b9e26d8324ae0496c85326b35e92bf617932d9/opentelemetry-semantic-conventions/src/opentelemetry/semconv/resource/__init__.py#L433

I tried adding:

```
"OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES": "service.version=4.3.2",
"OTEL_SERVICE_VERSION": "4.3.2",
```

in local.settings.json but that didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Azure Core OpenTelemetry Tracing [plugin](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-add-modify.md#python-1) for Python. This library enables tracing for Azure SDKs using the OpenTelemetry framework, allowing you to monitor and trace [applications](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/core/azure-core-tracing-opentelemetry/README.md).

```py
import azure.functions as func
import logging
from azure.core.settings import settings
from azure.core.tracing.ext.opentelemetry_span import OpenTelemetrySpan
from opentelemetry import trace
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace import TracerProvider
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import ConsoleSpanExporter
from opentelemetry.sdk.trace.export import SimpleSpanProcessor

# Enable OpenTelemetry tracing for Azure SDKs
settings.tracing_implementation = OpenTelemetrySpan

# Set up OpenTelemetry tracer
exporter = ConsoleSpanExporter()
trace.set_tracer_provider(TracerProvider())
tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)
trace.get_tracer_provider().add_span_processor(
    SimpleSpanProcessor(exporter)
)

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    with tracer.start_as_current_span(name="HTTPTriggerFunction"):
        logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

        name = req.params.get('name')
        if not name:
            try:
                req_body = req.get_json()
            except ValueError:
                pass
            else:
                name = req_body.get('name')

        if name:
            return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse(
                "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response.",
                status_code=200
            )
```

[image]

- The service details are found under attributes.
- Refer to this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702787/is-there-a-way-to-set-appname-in-application-insights-custom-events) to set the appName in Application Insights events.
- The code below sends telemetry data to Azure Monitor, creates a span with the name `hello`, and sets a custom attribute `"service.version"` with the value `"4.3.2"`.
- Here is the code for enabling Azure Monitor OpenTelemetry in Python applications, taken from [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/opentelemetry-enable?tabs=python).

**Code to add custom attributes/send custom dimensions:**

```py
from azure.monitor.opentelemetry import configure_azure_monitor
from opentelemetry import trace

# Configure Azure Monitor with your connection string
configure_azure_monitor(connection_string="AzureApplicationInsightsConnectionString")

# Get a tracer for the current module
tracer = trace.get_tracer(__name__)

# Start a new span with the name "hello" (or any span name you prefer)
with tracer.start_as_current_span("hello") as span:
    # Set the service version attribute on the span
    span.set_attribute("service.version", "4.3.2")
    span.set_attribute("OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES ", "service.version=4.3.2")
    print("Hello, World!")
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your extensive answer, much appreciated.

I indeed use the Azure Core OpenTelemetry Tracing library and the OTEL_SERVICE_NAME in the setings.json, as well as other custom dimension.

Since th number of custom dimensions is limited to 10, and the traces table of Application Insights contains a separate string column "application_Version", I hoped I could use that to store the version, instead of adding it as a custom dimension.

Your example shows that will not work, so I guess I'd have to go with a customDimension after all. ;)